# How to use to_categorical to convert [[4,7,10],[10,20,30]] to one hot encoding

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm working on LSTM's.

The output is categorical.

Its of format [[t11,t12,t13],[t21,t22,t23]

I was able to do it for 1d array and i'm finding it difficult to do it for 2d array.

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
print(to_categorical([[9,10,11],[10,11,12]]))
```

output

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

There were two different inputs each having 3 time steps, but in output its all combined.

I need it to be,

```
[[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]],

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]]
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? In theory you should just call `to_categorical` and that's it.

Comment: Your reshape should be 13, not 12.

Comment: Got it, thanks Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If shapes are weird, try to make it 1D, use the function, and reshape it back:

```
originalShape = myData.shape
totalFeatures = myData.max() + 1

categorical = myData.reshape((-1,))
categorical = to_categorical(categorical)
categorical = categorical.reshape(originalShape + (totalFeatures,))
```

Answer (score 3):

I realized i can achieve what I want by reshaping,

```
print(a.reshape(2,3,13))



[[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error when reshaping because the highest class index is 12 and therefore there are 13 classes (0, 1, ..., 12). To avoid such errors furthermore, you might Numpy let infer those dimension by calling `one_hot.reshape(sparse.shape + [-1])` where `one_hot` is the one-hot encoded vector produced by `to_categorical()` and `sparse` the orignal one.